# NFC send image/jpeg

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p

How can I send an image/jpeg from my app that uses NFC? According to the Android documentation, the NdefRecord createMime can do it for me. I have only used createUri for passing a URL to another Android device. But I am not sure how I can get started on converting my jpeg/image to an NdefRecord. It seems like I need to convert it into bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the answer to my question. What I was doing before was:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image1);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

NdefMessage img = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createMime("Test Image", byteArray));
```

And the result to this was a tag result of a string "Test Image". What I did was change the "**Test Image**" to "**image/jpeg**" and the result is the image was received on the other device. Only downside is from less than an hour of testing, sometimes a 2-3 KB image takes about 30 seconds the same as a 30 KB image.

Comment: Probably your nfc subsystem crashes from time to time when experiencing delay